# json to .net class n-ary tree?

Tags: .net, json, wcf, rest

```
{
"allnodes":[
{
    "nodes":[
        {
            "data":{
            "parentId":"1",
            "nodes":[

            ],
            "name":"a",
            "nodescount":0,
            "id":"2"
            }
        },
        {
            "data":{
            "parentId":"1",
            "nodes":[
                {
                    "data":{
                        "parentId":"3",
                        "nodes":[

                        ],
                        "name":"b",
                        "nodescount":0,
                        "id":"4"
                    }
                }
            ],
            "name":"c",
            "nodescount":1,
            "id":"3"
            }
        }
    ],
    "name":"d",
    "nodescount":2,
    "id":"1"
    }
    ]
}
```

**.net data contract**

```
  [DataContract]
   class Node
   {
      [DataMember(Name = "id")]
      public string id { get; set; }

      [DataMember(Name = "name")]
      public string name { get; set; }

      [DataMember(Name = "parentId")]
      public string ParentId { get; set; }

      [DataMember(Name = "nodescount")]
      public long Nodescount { get; set; }

      [DataMember(Name = "nodes")]
       public IEnumerable<Node> Nodes { get; set; }
   }
```

**wcf rest call**

```
     [WebGet(UriTemplate = "/abc/nodes",
     RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
     BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped)]
  void GetNodeTree(,
     [MessageParameter(Name = "allnodes")]
     out Node[] items);
```

**Problem:**
The problem i am having is that the internal nodes are not loaded with the right information, top level works and i can't seem to get what i am missing in my datacontract?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Node** class worked perfectly once I removed the object, as this was redundant

"data":{
}